# SSRS2008: LocalReport export to HTML / fragment

Tags: ssrs-2008

I need local RDL report to be exported to HTML, preferably HTML fragment. In 2005 it wasn't officially supported but there was a [trick](http://beaucrawford.net/post/Enable-HTML-in-ReportViewer-LocalReport.aspx). In SSRS2008 they seem to drop this support (there's no HTML extension in the supported extensions when enumerating using reflection) and use [RPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee301773.aspx) instead which is a binary format that I doubt someone will be happy to parse. Actually it's doesn't seem to be about HTML at all.

Now, is there a way to render HTML using SSRS2008 local report?

Notice that I use VS2008 but with reporting assemblies installed from VS2010 Beta 2 reportviewer.

Comment: Link for trick: http://web.archive.org/web/20100903204048/http://beaucrawford.net/post/Enable-HTML-in-ReportViewer-LocalReport.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I found a way, but it's not very good.
Export report to mhtml (it's supported by SSRS2008) 
Then use `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` for render mhtml.
In `wb.DocumentText` property will be full html page.

It's not very good, because you need a file (as url for WebBrowser).
And also, if I use WebBrowser in ASP.NET application, I need to process it in another thread, with STA ApartmentState.

Comment: You can load HTML without a file in the WebBrowser control. Just not mht.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for the same thing.  I suppose I suppose we could try to grab the rendered output of the ReportViewer somehow with reflection?

I might play around with it in a little bit to see what I can come up with.

Comment: I did not find the answer, so I just use ASP.NET report viewer inside ASP.NET MVC application.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the mht, you can extract it's content with [MIMER](https://github.com/smithimage/MIMER/).

There is a nu-get package here (MIMER will require .NET Framework 3.5):
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MIMER/

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;


using MIMER;


namespace MimerTest
{


    // https://github.com/smithimage/MIMER/blob/master/MIMERTests/MHT/MhtTests.cs
    // https://github.com/smithimage/MIMER/
    static class Program
    {



        /// <summary>
        /// Der Haupteinstiegspunkt für die Anwendung.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            if (false)
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }


            System.IO.Stream m_Stream;
            string path = @"d:\USERNAME\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\MimerTest\MimerTest\whatismht.mht";

            System.IO.FileInfo finf = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
            m_Stream = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

            var reader = new MIMER.RFC2045.MailReader();
            MIMER.IEndCriteriaStrategy endofmessage = new MIMER.RFC2045.BasicEndOfMessageStrategy();
            var message = reader.ReadMimeMessage(ref m_Stream, endofmessage);

            System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,string> allContents = message.Body;

            string strFile = allContents["text/html"];


            foreach (System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,string> kvp in allContents)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key);
                System.Console.WriteLine(kvp.Value);
            }



            System.Console.WriteLine(" --- Press any key to continue --- ");
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

In the 2005 ReportViewer, you can enable HTML via reflection:

```
private static void EnableFormat(ReportViewer viewer, string formatName)
{
     const BindingFlags Flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;

     FieldInfo m_previewService = viewer.LocalReport.GetType().GetField
     (
         "m_previewService",
         Flags
     );

     MethodInfo ListRenderingExtensions = m_previewService.FieldType.GetMethod
     (
         "ListRenderingExtensions",
         Flags
     );

     object previewServiceInstance = m_previewService.GetValue(viewer.LocalReport);

     IList extensions = ListRenderingExtensions.Invoke(previewServiceInstance, null) as IList;

     PropertyInfo name = extensions[0].GetType().GetProperty("Name", Flags);

     foreach (object extension in extensions)
     {
         if (string.Compare(name.GetValue(extension, null).ToString(), formatName, true) == 0)
         {
             FieldInfo m_isVisible = extension.GetType().GetField("m_isVisible", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
             FieldInfo m_isExposedExternally = extension.GetType().GetField("m_isExposedExternally", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
             m_isVisible.SetValue(extension, true);
             m_isExposedExternally.SetValue(extension, true);
             break;
         }
     }
 }
```

Usage:

```
var Viewer = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer();
EnableFormat(Viewer, "HTML4.0");
```

You might also find this interesting:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23966/Report-Viewer-generate-reports-MS-Word-formats